# What are the Dark Souls loading screen hints?

Tags: dark-souls

It's silly how fast my PC loads required game resources and I don't have enough time to read those loading screen hints/tips about in-game items. Screenshot button produces a blank screen, so I can't capture all loading screens and save them for reading. But maybe someone already saved them somehow or there is complete text of those hints.

What are all the tips that can be seen during the loading screen of Dark Souls?

Comment: I also found [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rdyUw.jpg) while searching for these hints. Seems like it's a known problem.

Answer (score 7):

The hints are description texts of the items that you can find in the game, like weapons, armors, consumables etc. You can read those descriptions any time if you toggle the details of any item in your inventory .. well, for those that you have.
There might be other hints, too, but I don't recall seeing anything else. You are not missing out on important gameplay tips or lore; you can find such information in other sources on the internet.

Answer (score 5):

I've compiled an album or screenshots of a youtube video that lists some of the hints:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOk3p.jpg

(*feel free to add more hints, post in text form with item images, or however you see it could be better*)